# Word for a Female Teenager?

Tags: word-choice, thesaurus

I am writing a book about a teenage girl. In one line, I am saying that she saw another female. When I say...

> she saw another girl

I think saying girl will make her sound like a child rather than a teenager (aged 15) and simply saying woman makes her seem more mature and like a woman in her 20's or older.

But saying...

> a teenage girl that was of an age similar to her

seems like over doing it and too many common words. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sending this to English, this is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet in this scenario will simply be to prevent the reader from forming any false impressions. You can do this by correcting him immediately after the word.

> She saw another girl, about fifteen years old.

You can use either girl or woman; be sure to use the word that you would use to describe the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your first example, if you establish beforehand that the protagonist is a teenager, the reader isn't liable to assume that the other girl is a child because of the **another** preceding the **girl** in the sentence.
 Putting **another girl** is enough for the reader to gather that this other chick is also a teen girl, because she is directly compared to the protagonist, and also is not described as little, or small, etc.